# Как передать несколько значений в аргумент argparse?

Tags: python, requests, argparse

Есть код:

```
import requests
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test get')
parser.add_argument("--ip")
args = parser.parse_args()

r = requests.get("https://api.mcsrvstat.us/ping/"+args.ip)
json = r.json()

print(json['version']['name'])
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы в `args.ip` можно было вводить несколько IP-адресов через пробел или запятую, например: `py test.py 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.2`, и получить от них ответы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечу на вопрос о том как заставить `argparse` читать несколько значений в одну переменную как список.

Воспользуйтесь параметром `nargs='+'`:

```
parser.add_argument("--ip", nargs='+', type=str, help='List of IPs', required=True)
```

По поводу того, как получить ответ от сервиса для нескольких IP - советую задать отдельный SO вопрос.